Old PHAsset videos from iCloud don't play
On screen A, I'm using a media picker (TLPhotoPicker to be exact) to allow users to select a video, which is then passed on to screen B as a PHAsset so it can played.
In screen B I've played around with various methods of getting a playable video, and they all work well except for one edge case: really old videos that are stored in the cloud aren't playable, even after having been downloaded. The emphasis here is on really old, as more recent cloud videos that need to be fetched from the cloud are playable.
The strange thing is that after fetching the really old cloud video, if I go back to screen A, deselect the video, and then reselect it, and then go forward again to screen B, it becomes playable. This makes me think that after being fetched from the cloud it's being stored as a different PHAsset or something, but I've compared the before and after AVURLAsset.url and PHAsset.localIdentifier in this case and they don't seem to change, so I'm not sure what's going on.
As mentioned, I've tried various methods in screen B for getting a playable video, such as:
    let options = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    
    options.progressHandler = { progress, _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.loadingProgress = progress
        }
    }
    
    phAsset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options) { input, info in
        if let input,
           let urlAsset = input.audiovisualAsset as? AVURLAsset {
            let url = urlAsset.url
            // play video from url...
        } else {
            // throw error...
        }
    }

and
    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.version = .original
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        
    options.progressHandler = { progress, error, stop, info in            
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.loadingProgress = progress
        }
    }
        
    let manager = PHImageManager()
    manager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: phAsset, options: options) { avAsset, stop, info in            
        if let avAsset {
            // play video from AVAsset...
        } else {
            // throw error...
        }
    }

No errors are ever thrown. The progress completes to 1.0 (ie 100%) as expected. Even stranger is that, unlike in this post, I can call these on the AVAsset and they always indicate that the video is ready to be played:
let tracks = try await avAsset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .video) //  tracks exist.
let duration = try await avAsset.load(.duration) // duration is accurate.
let isPlayable = try await avAsset.load(.isPlayable) // isPlayable is true.

I found this post about the issue being that the PHVideoRequestOptions.version has to be .original, but that still doesn't work in this edge case.
Any ideas?
